# How to convert a array object to use with MUI's Autocomplete field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to convert my incoming object into something usable by MUI's Autcomplete object, however, I'm struggling to do this.

The code I have currently is as follows:

```
const [contactList, setContactList] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
        fetch(CONTACTS_URL, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {"Authorization": sessionStorage.getItem("accessToken")}
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseData) => {
            setContactList({responseData});
        })
        .catch((error) => console.error(error));
    }, [])
```

Which produces the following when printed to console:

```
Object
    responseData: Array(1)
        0: 
            {
                contactId: 1, 
                contactName: 'Cool Contact',
                firstLetter: "C"
            }
     length: 1
     [[Prototype]]: Array(0)
     [[Prototype]]: Object
```

The docs for Autocomplete say I need to do this:

```
const options = top100Films.map((option) => {
    const firstLetter = option.title[0].toUpperCase();
    return {
      firstLetter: /[0-9]/.test(firstLetter) ? '0-9' : firstLetter,
      ...option,
    };
});

<Autocomplete
      id="grouped-demo"
      options={options.sort((a, b) => -b.firstLetter.localeCompare(a.firstLetter))}
      groupBy={(option) => option.firstLetter}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
      sx={{ width: 300 }}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="With categories" />}
/>
```

However, the example above is under the impression you're using an already pre-defined constant, whereas mine is not quite like that.

How would I go about converting mine into something that can be used by Autocomplete?

Comment: It's not really clear what your asking. You have an array of options, so pass it to `Autocomplete`? Also, please read [mre]. Your question is lacking details.

Comment: after `setContactList({responseData});` you have to `console.log(contactList)`  to make sure what data you are getting from fetch api

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just pass contactList to the `options` prop, and provide a callback for `getOptionLabel`.

And, instead of calling `setContactList` with an object, just pass the array directly. That way, `contactList` is an array of options.

```
  const [contactList, setContactList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(CONTACTS_URL, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: { Authorization: sessionStorage.getItem('accessToken') },
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseData) => {
        setContactList(responseData);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  }, []);

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      options={contactList}
      getOptionLabel={(contact) => contact.contactName}
    />
  );
```

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, I did it slightly incorrectly and it kept erroring out. However, this did work!

Comment: @JamieRhys glad to hear that you solved it